# ARM template to create a VM using an existing VNet and subnet

Tags: json, azure, azure-resource-manager

recently I started learning/working with ARM templates and JSON so I'm a complete newbie to this. I've been asked to make a template that creates a virtual machine selecting an existing virtual network and subnet within a subscription.

Everything works fine, except that whenever I make the deployment, the template creates a new vnet and subnet with randomized names instead of letting me pick from an existing one (the VM creates correctly though).

I used https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/blob/master/101-vm-simple-rhel/azuredeploy.json quickstart template as a base and added a few lines (which I will put below) to let me type the name of my vnet and subnet as it does with the VM name, but it keeps creating new ones even though I type the name correctly.

The lines I added to the code in the **Parameters** section are:

```
"virtualNetworkName": {
    "type": "string",
    "metadata": {
        "description": "VNet to which the VM will connect."
    }
},
"subnetName": {
    "type": "string",
    "metadata": {
        "description": "Subnet to which the VM will connect."
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create a VM with the existing VNet base on the quickstart template you used, you only need to delete the virtual network resource in the `resources` block and the dependency on it and all the variables about the VNet and subnet except the variable `subnetRef`, then change this variable with your parameters like this if the VNet in the same resource group with the VM:

```
"subnetRef": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets', parameters('virtualNetworkName'), parameters('subnetName'))]",
```

If the existing VNet in another resource group but in the same subscription, then the variable `subnetRef` should be changed like this:

```
"subnetRef": "[resourceId('otherResourceGroup', 'Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets', parameters('virtualNetworkName'), parameters('subnetName'))]",
```

According to the changes, the template will use the existing VNet and subnet instead of creating new ones.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this sample:

https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/100-marketplace-sample

It shows how you can use a pattern for new/existing/none on resources in a template.